# Disable power button for iPad in MDM Single App Mode

Tags: ios, ipad, mdm, guided-access

If I set up an iPad to use the iOS guided access feature then it is possible to disable the home button AND the power button. This means the device can't be locked by a user. But if I activate single app mode via MDM locking the device remains possible, but the home button is disabled.

Is it possible to either configure a device to disable the power button or to start the "regular" guided access feature via MDM which one can start in settings?

Answer (score 1):

b,

Apple Profile Manager (available in the MAC OS X Server.app) allows MDM control allowing yoiu to specify setting Single App mode.  There is a flag that enables/disables the sleep/wake button.  If sleep/wake is active you can sleep/wake the ios device.

If sleep/wake is disabled you cannot put the ios device to sleep.

Correction: If Sleep/wake is enabled you can power off, when the device is locked (before passcode entry) you will be able to hold the power button then slide to power off.  If the device is unlocked, the single app mode will not present the slide to unlock if you hold the power button.

Answer (score 0):

MDM documentation doesn't specificy that AppLock profile has any special flags which specify whether power button is enabled or disabled. So, it looks you can turn on/off through MDM only mode where home button is disabled and power button is enabled.

Comment: Do you know a way to specify the guided access/app locking via profile setting in a way that the power button is locked?